# Factorization and the difference of two squares

Tags: number-theory, prime-factorization

While contemplating on the mathematics behind RSA cryptography, I tried to play around how to possibly find the factors $p,q$ in a rather more algebraic and elementary way. What I initially found out that I can manage to factor any odd number $c$ if I could somehow manage to find integer solutions to $a^2 – b^2 = c$. If non trivial solution exists, then if $c=p \cdot q$ then $p=a-b$ and $q=a+b$. This is of course provided that $c$ is not a perfect square so that $p$ and $q$ will be distinct.

Example: $$c=15=3\cdot5$$
$$p,q=3,5$$
$$a,b=4,1$$
$$4^2 – 1^2 = 15$$

My questions are:

1. Is this approach to factorization trivial and not at all new?
2. In terms of computational algorithms, is this more efficient or worse than other factorization algorithm?

PS: This technique can also be extended to factorization of any odd non perfect square number. The trivial solution will be: if $c=2k+1$, then $a=k+1$ is a solution.

Comment: Any expression of $c$ as the value of a reducible polynomial  would work.  If you could write $c=a^2+5ab+6b^2$, say, then you'd know that $c=(a+2b)(a+3b)$.  But...so what?  There's no apparent way to test $c$ for that property.

Comment: Yes I understand that. But my question is definitely about using such argument as means to obtain an algorithm to find, say, the factors any odd number $c$. Example would be try to rearrange the equation into: $b^2=a^2+c$. Given $c$ iterate values to $a$ and then check if whether $a^2+c$ is a perfect square.

Comment: But, again, we could do that with any reducible polynomial.  In the end, you are just doing a simple search through all the numbers less than $c$, and if you are going to do that then why not just ask, in turn, if each number you try is a factor of $c$?  At least with that method you can restrict your search to primes which might save a lot of time.

Comment: Take a look at Fermat factorization method.  
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_factorization_method

Comment: It is hopeless to find a non-trivial difference of two squares equal to a huge composite number, unless the number is very special, for example having almost equal prime factors. In general, the mehod will be inferior to a usual factorization plan.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question... but

> 1. Is this approach to factorization trivial and not at all new?

Whether it's trivial is subjective, but it's not new. For instance, *An Introduction to Mathematical Cryptography*'s Chapter 3.6 explains a fairly comprehensive approach based on this idea.

> 2. In terms of computational algorithms, is this more efficient or worse than other factorization algorithm?

As Peter says in the comment, it's statistically impossible to find a non-trivial difference by randomly trying a number. So, the idea isn't efficient as is.